# Question about transversals of finite groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $H$ be a subgroup of a finite group $G$ and let $\{t_i\}$ be a transversal such that $G=\bigcup_iHt_i$. My lecturer has written in his notes that this implies that for any $g\in G$ and $t_j\in \{t_i\}$ there exists a unique $h\in H$ and $t_k\in \{t_i\}$ such that $t_jg=ht_k$. I am wondering why this is true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The union $G=\cup_i Ht_i$ is disjoint. Thus, $t_jg$, as an element of $G$, is in exactly one of the union's elements, let's say $Ht_k$.

Therefore it is of the form $ht_k$ (which is general element of $Ht_k$) for some $h\in H$.

There isn't anything deeper here, it follows directly from the definitions and claims you wrote above.

Comment: Thank you very much.